# ASP.NET MVC application, localhost working, remote computer returning "An error occurred while processing your request."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am currently running an MVC application written with C#/Razor. Thus far it is quite simple - I have a database created, and am cycling through it to print all of the values. If the user is an admin or if domain account of the user equals the name in the database, then they may edit that row in the database.

When I run this locally on the PC I created it with, navigating to `http://localhost/ApplicationName`, the page works perfectly. If I navigate to `"PC-Name/ApplicationName"`, peculiarly, the site renders correctly, but none of the JavaScript or JQuery will function - what might be causing this ?

More worryingly, when I navigate to this address, `"PC-Name/ApplicationName"` from a remote PC on the same network/domain, the message "Error.An error occurred while processing your request." appears in large, red writing.

[image]

In my application, if I comment out the following lines where I am printing from my database, the error message disappears:

```
@model IEnumerable<WhoIs.Models.Employee>
...
    @foreach ( var prod in Model )
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@prod.Field1</td> 
                    <td>@prod.Field2</td> 
                    <td>@prod.Field3</td> 
                    <td>@prod.DomainAC</td> 
                    @if (User.IsInRole(@"Admin") || User.Identity.Name == prod.DomainAC) {
                            <td><a href="/home/edit/@prod.Id"  style="color: blue;">edit</a></td>
                     }
                </tr>
             }
```

I have a .edmx file added to my models folder which is linked to a remote database. I have tried to edit the web.config to give more information on what may be the problem by adding the lines :

```
  <compilation debug="true"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
```

But I am still only getting the error message above.

Can anyone offer any guidance on what may be the problem here, or how I can find more debug information to try to find the root of this ?

Comment: The javascript problem is possibly same domain access policy issues, what does your browser debugging tool say in the console?

Comment: Have you configured your firewall correctly to allow your machine to host applications remotely?

Comment: If you have access to the remote server, navigate to your url from the remote server itself, it should give you a more detailed error message that way.

Comment: @CharlieBrown - No firewall; No errors on the browser debugging tool! Can't find any meaningful information here really!

Comment: @Mansfield I have access to the remote server - navigating to the URL produces no error message also; but the JS still will not function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error running on a virtual machine in Amazon AWS.

The website had been working some time ago.. like a few months when I left it last.  No configuration changes, nothing.  Now it doesn't work.... And why would it stop working?  Real head scratcher.  Maybe a virus infection - It was not set to auto patch... Hmmm..

I'd set the machine to the smallest (micro instance) as a kind of "hibernation" of the site, very little traffic expected and I didn't have this site on my list of priorities...  The site "worked" in "micro" instance when I last left it.  Tried rebooting first off. Nothing.

Then I checked the localhost and it works from there.  Weird.

Anyway it is time to make some modifications on this site and some upgrades.  "Micro" instances are useless when upgraded so I shut it down and rebooted as a "small" instance.  Hey presto the site works remotely again no config changes.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The message you see is in your default error pages that comes with the auto generated code of your project. You can get more information of the error using ViewData dictionary in the error page like this:

`@ViewData["Message"]`

(I know you can handle ViewData)

If you are having this error is, maybe, because you have and unhabled error in your model code. Go to your site settings on web.config and activate debuging with stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout". Create the two folder. Your logs are going to be in .\logs. Check the newest log every time you see the error message. It will tell you the line number of your error.

Your logs folder should be inside the site folder. Ej: c:\www\sitename\logs\stdout.

I hope this helps. Good luck.